# Live Preview highlight in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3, highlight, live-preview

how to set live preview highlight in sublime text editor, like bracket text editor. when you select a selector in css it shows blue border around that selector in livepreview in brackets texteditor.is there any plug in sublime text do the same.

Comment: Perhaps you can include an image of what you want to achieve?